# HttpContext does not exist in System.Web

Tags: .net-core, console-application

I created a new project with the template "Console App (.NET Core)".
So when I try manually referencing `System.Web` through "Add reference", there will be no reference tab.

Can anyone help how to add reference of `HttpContext`?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmXon.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The System.Web based HttpContext is a class in .NET Framework (versions 1-4) and not available in either .NET Core (Version 1-3) or .NET (version 5 or 6).

In a console application the current HttpContext will always be null. If you are creating a .NET Core web application, you can read the documentation in the following link to access current HttpContext.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0

May be if you provide more details about what you are trying to achieve by using HttpContext in a console application, you will get a better answer.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this in the ExceptionLogging class for `private static String exurl = context.Current.Request.Url.ToString();` and `string filepath = context.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExceptionDetailsFile/");`

Comment: I have declared context at the top as `using context = System.Web.HttpContext;`

Comment: This won't work.
In a console application there is NO HttpContext.
Also System.Web.HttpContext doesn't exist in .NET Core.

If you want to get the path of file to log exception relative to current directory use:
`var filepath = Path.GetFullPath("./ExceptionDetailsFile");`

Current request Url doesn't exist  if you are in a console application, this applies only for web applications.